# GET method retrieve tickets with zendesk API (php)

Tags: php, json, zendesk

I'm not very good in php, but i don't understand why my code is not working it's like the function is not even launch because i receive nothing not even an error.

here is my code:

```
<?php

define("ZDAPIKEY", "MYTOKEN");
define("ZDUSER", "MYUSER");

$lauchnfunction = curlWrap();

/* Note: do not put a trailing slash at the end of v2 */
function curlWrap()
{
    $ch = curl_init();
  $url = "https://cubber.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets/recent.json";
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10 );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, ZDUSER."/token:".ZDAPIKEY);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/json'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "MozillaXYZ/1.0");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $decoded = json_decode($output);
    return $decoded;
  $data = curlWrap("/tickets/recent.json", null, "GET");
  var_dump($data);
}

?>
```

of course i replace MYTOKEN and MYUSER with my real value

Comment: @SearchAndResQ that looks like it would become and infinite recursion

Comment: Yes it's an infinite recursion.

Comment: You should try to var_dump `$lauchnfunction`; also, I don't know if this causes any issue, but the line `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");` doesn't seem very useful, you can try to remove it or comment it out

Comment: @mishu you are right, i did var_dum(lauchnfunction) and i receive all my data :) thanks a lot

Comment: you are welcome, I am glad I could help